# zoom_changed listener doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use a zoom listener event in a google maps so that I can resize some axis I have in it. As a beginning, I'm trying to use an alert so that I can see whether if the listener detects a change in the zoom level or not, but I'm not able to get any alert at all. My code is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps - pygmaps </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.801674, 11.188139);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: centerlatlng,
            scaleControl:true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

*** plotting stuff ***

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(maps,'zoom_changed', function()
{
    alert("changed");
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <button onclick="draw_axis()">Enable/Disable Axis</button> <br><br>    <div id="log"></div>  
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 90%;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` variable isn't defined when you create the zoom_changed listener, it is created later, when the initialize function runs (also the variable is `map`, not `maps`).

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  var centerlatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.801674, 11.188139);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 18,
    center: centerlatlng,
    scaleControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    alert("changed");
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <div id="log"></div>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 90%;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `zoom_changed` event on the instance of `google.maps.Map` inside your `initialize()` function.

```
map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    alert("changed");
});
```